# Regex to import weblogs into Hive correctly

Tags: regex, hadoop, expression, hive

I am trying to come up with a regex so that I can use to import weblogs into Hive. I am no regex expert and I am having issues trying to handle two different transaction types in the logs with different metadata.

The logs contain a Request and a Reply transaction, the regex I have come up with caters for the Request transaction but fails on the Reply as the reply contains a 'Heartbeat' in the data. 
The logs can contain up to twenty thousand or more entries per day.

**My Regex so far**

```
    (^[0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)   ([^ ]*)   ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)(?:[:]) ([0-9]+.[0-9]+(?:\ms)) ([^ ]*)(?:[:]) (.*)\n
```

**Expected results:**

1. The regex has to handle Heartbeat data in the Reply and no data in the Request
2. In the data, I do not want to import the ':' colon at the end of the Transaction types and end of the SessionKey. The regex I have implemented above appears to exclude it, but I am not sure if it is correct.
3. In the Heartbeat response, a timestamp and 'ms' milliseconds is returned in the message, originally the words 'ms' was to be imported as demonstrated in the regex above, but now I need to exclude it from the import and I am having issues getting the correct expression to exclude

**Weblog examples:**

***Request Transaction:***

**Sample Data**

```
0 20140625095038864 20140625095038864 0000 006 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 Request: fafe805e-614e-41dd-9b0f-8ec5fbc8c882
```

**Structure:**

```
Version = 0 
EventTime = 20140625095038864 
LogTime = 20140625095038864 
SequenceNumber = 0000 
Level = 006 
InternalArea = 00/0000/000 
MachineName = LSEMPPRD   
ApplicationName = Nestra   
DiscardedMessageCount = 000 000000 00 
TranType = Request: 
SessionKey = fafe805e-614e-41dd-9b0f-8ec5fbc8c882
Message = <GetAccountInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><accountSession     xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><b:SessionKey>8c737876-fccb-4352-8d06-9f19ccb34fd6</b:SessionKey><b:SessionToken i:nil="true"></b:SessionToken></accountSession></GetAccountInfo>
```

***Reply Transaction:***

**Sample Data**

```
0 20140625095038615 20140625095038646 0000 006 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 Reply: 296.4057ms d594891a-6d9c-4b5c-913a-9dc302277534:
```

**Structure:**

```
Version = 0 
EventTime = 20140625095038615 
LogTime = 20140625095038646 
SequenceNumber = 0000 
Level = 006 
InternalArea = 00/0000/000 
MachineName = LSEMPPRD  
ApplicationName = Nestra   
DiscardedMessageCount = 000 000000 00 
TranType = Reply: 
Heartbeat = 296.4057ms 
SessionKey = d594891a-6d9c-4b5c-913a-9dc302277534:
Message = <GetAccountInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><accountSession xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><b:SessionKey>8c737876-fccb-4352-8d06-9f19ccb34fd6</b:SessionKey><b:SessionToken i:nil="true"></b:SessionToken></accountSession></GetAccountInfo>
```

Comment: you want to store the request and response data into same table ?

Comment: Yes, I intend on loading the data into hive via a Create table statement, I just need to get the correct regex for the "input.regex".

Comment: ok got u ! plz find the answer and accept if it solves your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here find the answer :

Note: make sure about spaces used. test in [rubular](http://rubular.com/) before using

Regex :

```
(^[0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)   ([^ ]*)   ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)(?:[:]) ([0-9]+.[0-9]+|)(?:ms |)([^ ]*)(?:[:])
```

Data : 2 lines

```
0 20140625095038864 20140625095038864 0000 006 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 Request: fafe805e-614e-41dd-9b0f-8ec5fbc8c882:
0 20140625095038615 20140625095038646 0000 006 00/0000/000 LSEMPPRD   Nestra   000 000000 00 Reply: 296.4057ms d594891a-6d9c-4b5c-913a-9dc302277534:
```

Regex : (Complete - to handle message part also) - just add at end :      **(.*$)**

```
(^[0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)   ([^ ]*)   ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)(?:[:]) ([0-9]+.[0-9]+|)(?:ms |)([^ ]*)(?:[:]) (.*$)
```

[image]

Verification: [rubular](http://rubular.com/)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Ramisetty, thank you for the response and I tested the regex and it returns the data broken up as expected. One issue which I forgot to include in my Data sample was the 'Message =' part at the end. I included in the structure part of the example above, I need to import all that data at the end as a string into one column so that I can query the xml data via Xpath. Are you able to assist with the last part of the regex?

Comment: updated ! plz find and accept the same if found useful

Comment: Thank you very much ramisetty.vijay for your prompt response, your answer was exactly what I was looking for.